# Why is my libgdx game using more RAM every time I switch screen?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, libgdx

I made a game that contains two screens so far, a main menu, and a game screen. However I noticed that every time I switch from the main menu to the game screen that it used up like 50-60mb more RAM. Not too much, but that's not all of it.

When I return to the main menu it goes down with like 30-40mb. And when I hit play again it raises up with 50-60mb again. This way it alway uses up more RAM the more I switch through the screens. It also slowly starts using more RAM when it's just on the game screen too. Not as big of a deal as with the screen switching, but still.

I've tried to dispose as much as I could and I've also tried to use the gc, but it still won't stop with this behaviour. down here is some of my code:

Game class

```
 public class MyGame extends Game {

public OrthographicCamera camera;
public SpriteBatch batch;

public static final int WIDTH = 800;
public static final int HEIGHT = 450;

public static MainMenu mainmenu;

@Override
public void create() {

    mainmenu = new MainMenu(this);

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(true, 1920, 1080);

    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    setScreen(mainmenu);
}

public void dispose(){
    this.getScreen().dispose();
    batch.dispose();
}

}
```

Main menu class:

```
public class MainMenu implements Screen{

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private MyGame game;

private Stage stage;
private Sprite bground;
private SpriteDrawable bgsprite;
private TextureAtlas atlas;
private Button playbutton, aboutbutton;
private Table table;
private Skin skin;
private Sound btnclick;

public MainMenu(final MyGame game){
    this.game = game;

    stage = new Stage();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    btnclick = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("sounds/button_click.wav"));

    atlas = new TextureAtlas("atlas/newbuttons.pack");
    skin = new Skin(atlas);
    table = new Table(skin);
    table.setBounds(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),        Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    Texture bground_texture = new Texture("grass_HD_new.png");
    bground_texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
    bground = new Sprite(bground_texture);

    bgsprite = new SpriteDrawable(bground);

    ButtonStyle playbuttonstyle = new ButtonStyle();
    playbuttonstyle.up = skin.getDrawable("play_button_up");
    playbuttonstyle.down = skin.getDrawable("play_button_down");
    playbutton = new Button(playbuttonstyle);
    playbutton.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
         @Override
         public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
             btnclick.play(0.1F);
             ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
             dispose(); 
         }
    });

    ButtonStyle aboutbuttonstyle = new ButtonStyle();
    aboutbuttonstyle.up = skin.getDrawable("about_button_up");
    aboutbuttonstyle.down = skin.getDrawable("about_button_down");
    aboutbutton = new Button(aboutbuttonstyle);
    aboutbutton.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
         @Override
         public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
             btnclick.play(0.3F);
         }
    });

    table.add(playbutton).spaceBottom(30);
    table.row();
    table.add(aboutbutton);
    table.background(bgsprite);
    stage.addActor(table);

}

@Override
public void show() {

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();
}

public void update(float delta){

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    stage.dispose();
    bgsprite.getSprite().getTexture().dispose();
    bground.getTexture().dispose();
    atlas.dispose();
    skin.dispose();
    btnclick.dispose();
}
}
```

render method in game screen:
(the class is pretty large so I didn't want to include all of it)

```
    @Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    game.camera.update();

    if(paused || bombTouched){
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Keys.ESCAPE)){
            paused = false;
        }
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Keys.M)){
            ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new MainMenu(game));
            dispose();
        }
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Keys.R)){
            bombTouched = false;
        }
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Keys.Q)){
            Gdx.app.exit();
        }
    }else{
        update(delta);
    }

    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(game.camera.combined);

    game.batch.begin();

        game.batch.draw(sprite, 0, 0);


        for(Coin coin : coin.rect) {
            game.batch.draw(coin.getSprite(), coin.getBounds().x, coin.getBounds().y);
        }

        for(Bomb bomb : bomb.rect) {
            game.batch.draw(bomb.getSprite(), bomb.getBounds().x, bomb.getBounds().y);
        }


        game.batch.draw(snail.getSprite(), snail.getBounds().x, snail.getBounds().y);

        font.draw(game.batch, "score:   " + score, 100, 980);
        fps.draw(game.batch, "fps: " + Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond(), 20, 30);

        if(paused){
            game.batch.draw(pause_sprite, 0, 0);
        }

        if(bombTouched){
            game.batch.draw(gameover_sprite, 0, 0);
        }

    game.batch.end();
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're forgetting to dispose of something big in your GameScreen class.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought too, but I can't seem to find anything more to dispose there.

Comment: I guess it's the SpriteBatch that's not being disposed when I switch screens since it's in the MyGame class. However, when I tried to use it in my Game Screen class and dispose it there, my game threw an OpenGLExeption when I tried to go back to the Main Menu.

Comment: That would be the issue if your GameScreen class instantiates a new one. It would be bad practice to dispose of something in a class other than the one that instantiated it because that would get very hard to keep track off. By the way, Stage instantiates its own sprite batch if you don't pass one into its constructor. That's wasteful.

Comment: In each class that owns Disposables, I create an Array<Disposable> and fill it with every object that implements Disposable, immediately after instantiating them. Then in the `dispose` method, I can dispose everything with a simple for loop on the array. This makes it easy to avoid forgetting something.

Comment: Hmm, could it possibly be the coin and bomb objects? they're actually rectangles so I can make use of collision detection. They're spawned in an array and get's rendered as soon as they get there. They are removed after small amount of time tho. And the textures are disposed at the same time. Doesn't seem like it'd be the cause either...

Comment: And yeah, I could try out that Array if nothing else works.